# Serving through a carbonation stone

Tags: carbonation, kegging, serving

Are there any disadvantages to leaving a diffuser stone (0.5micron) in the keg for serving?  The one I had bought is attached to a replacement SS dip tube and permanently in the keg.

My option would be to transfer to a new keg after carbonation, but... extra cleaning/sani/time/effort and chance of O2/contam.   In other words, if it's not a big factor, and the stone will still bubble gas up to the headspace for serving, I won't bother.

To take that further, after I get my carb to the desired volume using temp chart, wetting psi, atmospheric, and elevation, do I leave gas at that setting or lower it to regular chart pressure to just push out the beer at that CO2 volume?

Answer (score 3):

Serving using a submerged carbonation stone is less than ideal.

It will stir up sediment that's usually undisturbed on the bottom of the keg.

Also the sudden burst of cO2 will cause head foam in the keg. Cleaning that dried lacing from the keg won't be fun.

I've never seen one that attaches directly to the normal gas port. Ideally the stones are attached to a custom lid with its own port. So when ready to serve you change the lid or just attach cO2 to the standard gas port.

If your stone attaches to the normal gas port and is on a short tube so that it's indented for the keg to be inverted while carbonating. But isn't in the beer while upright, then it wount have any issues.

Second question: Your serving system should pour at the same pressure used to carbonate most beer styles so the cO2 volumes don't change while it's on tap. Line size and length are critical.

Comment: I bought it from one of the big online stores, however, the item has since been replaced with the _hose/lid_ style.  The thin SS tube goes up through the normal Gas dip tube and attaches at the top.  It looks like it is the same part as an O2 wand.  In order to disassemble, I have to begin by removing the post...  This would obviously make it hard with a full keg.

Comment: @Stevo Cheap solution: Cut it as short as possible and carbonate with the keg inverted.

Comment: Cut short and invert--Perfect!!!   Now, after carb and right side up, the stone will not be in solution.  Should I subtract wetting psi for serving or leave it alone?

Comment: @Stevo I don't know what "wetting psi"  is. I would just slow carb at a constant psi for a few days rather than high for short time

Comment: Wetting psi is the amount of pressure to push the gas through the resistance of the stone

Comment: @Stevo I've never had the need to increase psi to get gas to flow through a carb stone wet or dry.

Comment: Middle of page 1 (starts para 9) and page two describe. https://chme.nmsu.edu/files/2016/06/Brite-tank-carbonation.pdf

Comment: I see little use for this process since it only takes 2-8 psi to do, you will carbonate all beers above that.  I believe this is just a best practice to make sure gas is flowing before getting stone wet to prevent clogs.

Comment: @Evil Zymurgist Wetting pressure is a constant pressure drop across the carb stone. If you're carbing according to ASBC or Zahm Nagel tables it has to be added to the tabulated pressure.

Comment: @KevinSharp a carb stone adds resistance. If carbonating beer needed a specific volume flow then this would be a factor, but it's not. Even if just one molecule of co2 was able to escape at a time it will eventually carbonate the beer to the proper volumes with no added "wetting pressure". I believe there is some confusion with the phrase. The only reason to increase the pressure would be in a large bright tank were the fluid pressure at the base needs to be overcome because of the depth of the beer.

Comment: I think you're assuming that wetting pressure is just normal flow resistance - it isn't. It's a form of capillary pressure. All carbonation stones have a minimum gas pressure that must be applied before any flow will occur. If, for example, your regulator pressure is 8psi and the wetting pressure of the stone is 3psi  then the gas pressure at the liquid interface will be 5psi when the system is at equilibrium. If you google the term "wetting pressure" you will find plenty of reputable sources that explain this.

Comment: @KevinSharp cool I learned something! Yes wetting pressure fluid dinamic property. So indeed it's not just resistance, 2-8 psi is needed to defeat the stone,. So wetting pressure + head fluid pressure + carb pressure = psi needed.